# laravel - Update one to many polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have three tables in one to many polymorphic relationship

```
┌─────────────────┐          ┌─────────────────┐          ┌──────────────────┐
│ users           │          │ phones          │          │ departments      │
├─────────────────┤          ├─────────────────┤          ├──────────────────┤
| id              |          | id              |          | id               |
| name            |          | name            |          | name             |
└─────────────────┘          | phones_type     |          └──────────────────┘
                             | phones_id       |          
                             └─────────────────┘
```

Phone Model:

```
public function phones()
 {
   return $this->morphTo();
 }
```

User Model:

```
public function phones()
 {
   return $this->morphMany('App\Phone', 'phones');
 }
```

Department Model:

```
public function phones()
 {
   return $this->morphMany('App\Phone', 'phones');
 }
```

Now I want to update phone numbers so the user can edit/add/remove numbers .. I can’t figure it in one step so I tried to delete all phones first then add the new numbers

My Code:
DepartmentController :

```
public function update(UpdateDepartment $request, Department $department)
    {
        $department->phones()->delete();
        $department->name = $request['name'];
        $department->save();
        foreach ($request->phone as $value) {
            $phone = new Phone;
            $phone->name = $value;
            $ department->phones()->save($phone);
        }
    }
```

UpdateDepartment.php :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|alpha_spaces|min:3|max:255|unique: department,name,'.$this-> department ->id,
            'phone'    => 'required|array|unique:phones,name,'
            'phone.*'  => 'required|distinct|unique:phones,name,',
        ];
    }
```

I have two questions :

1-  Is that the right way to do that ? is there any way to sync updated phone numbers in one step?

2- If this is the way ...   How to forcing a unique rule To ignore a given ID if the user just add phone numbers to the existing numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

1 - You could send some identifier (id) with new phone number, so You will know what exactly phщne are modified, for example put some `data-id="{{ $phone->id }}"` to phone field and build request with javascript to make something like this:

```
"phones":
  {
    "1"(your phone id):"+123456789",
    "2":"+123654978",
  }
```

And than iterate trough request data like this:

```
public function update(UpdateDepartment $request, Department $department)
{
    $department->name = $request['name'];
    foreach ($request->phones as $id => $value) {
        $department->phones->transform(function($item) use ($id, $value){
            if($item->id == $id) {
                $item->name = $value;
                $item->save(); //if You using laravel 5 You need to savve each phone model separately
            }
        });
    }

    $department->push(); //if You using laravel 6.x, this will save model with all changed/created relations
}
```

[more about `push()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#the-push-method)

### UPD

But I would advise storing phone numbers as `json` in a separate field for users and departments, then it will be possible to simply replace the old set of numbers in model with a new one from request without making unnecessary queries to the database.